# Repeated crossvalidation on subset of data in MLR

Tags: r, mlr

I am trying to set up an `mlr` classification task where 75% of the data is to be used for training, and this 75% will be resampled by repeated cross validation.

My setup of the task is as follows

```
pred.Bin.Task <- makeClassifTask(id="CountyCrime", data=df, target="count.bins")
preProc.Task <- normalizeFeatures(pred.Bin.Task, method="range")
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("RepCV", reps=3, folds=5)
inTraining <- caret::createDataPartition(df$count.bins, p = .75, list = FALSE)
```

But I couldn't get the resampling to work. When I do `lda.train <- resample("classif.lda", preProc.Task, rdesc, subset=inTraining)`

I get the error

```
Error in setHyperPars2.Learner(learner, insert(par.vals, args)) : 
  classif.lda: Setting parameter subset without available description object!
You can switch off this check by using configureMlr!
```

Training without subsetting (i.e.  `lda.train <- resample("classif.lda", preProc.Task, rdesc)` ) works.

I'd rather have the whole data rather than just the training data in the Task, so that when I do prediction with the holdout data I don't need to pre-process and resubmit new data. Any suggestions on how I can get the subsetting right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the error is that the `resample` function doesn't have a `subset` argument, so it's passed through to the learner, which does not have such an argument either.

`mlr`'s resample descriptions don't allow you to keep data completely separate (i.e. not use it at all during training) as you're trying to do. However, you can use the `subsetTask` function to partition the data without having to preprocess again:

```
preproc.task.train = subsetTask(preproc.task, inTraining)
resample("classif.lda", preproc.task.train, rdesc)
```